# error messages in a different language

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint Online site that is created with English.

When I try to invite an extern user to the site if something goes wrong the user gets an error message in a different language (NOT English).

**What can be causing this?**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that an alternate language is configured for the site (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-the-languages-you-want-to-make-available-for-a-site-s-user-interface-16d3a83c-05ab-4b50-8fbb-ff576a3351e8)) and the user has this language set as one of his spoken languages (see [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7))

Comment: no. the only language installed on this site collection is English. there are no alternative languages at all. Also the user that gets the errors in a different language is an external user. so it shouldn't matter. Parent is English only. how in the world can somebody that is not from the organisation get error messages in a different language than English is beyond me.